# Use SQLITE ODBC with .NET on MAC OS

Tags: macos, sqlite, .net-core

Hi I'm trying to do a very simple program in .NET (3.1 Core or 5) something like this:

```
using System;
using System.Data.Odbc;

namespace testsqlite
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
        var conn = new OdbcConnection();
            conn.ConnectionString = "Driver=SQLITE3;Database=Orders.db;LongNames=0;Timeout=1000;NoTXN=0;SyncPragma=NORMAL;StepAPI=0;";
            conn.Open();
            var stmt = conn.CreateCommand();
            stmt.CommandText = "Select * from customer";
            using (var reader = stmt.ExecuteReader()) 
            {
               var message = reader.GetString(0);
               Console.WriteLine(message);
            }
            Console.WriteLine("Hello World!");
        }
    }
}
```

I installed sqlite3 and also installed the driver using `brew install sqliteodbc` but it does now seem to work. When I run I get:Unhandled exception. System.Data.Odbc.OdbcException (0x80131937): ERROR [01000] [unixODBC][Driver Manager]Can't open lib 'SQLITE3' : file not found

Any ideas of what I might be missing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok I found a way to make it work.

1. Before you start make sure that you have sqlite installed.
   If not run `brew install sqlite`.
2. Second install the sqlite odbc driver by running `brew install sqliteodbc`

> NOTE: you might need to do `brew install upgrade sqliteodbc`

3. After installing the sqliteodbc driver, you need to run `odbcinst -j`. You do this to validate your unixODBC installation because you need to know where is the `odbcinst.ini` file in your system.
   [image: ODBSINST output]

> For example in my case it was /usr/local/etc/odbcinst.ini

4. Before you edit the ini file you need to know where is the odbc library for sqlite installed. run `brew test sqliteodbc`
   [image: getting odbc lib location]
5. Finally modify your `odbcinst.ini` to include a location for the odbc driver
   [image: odbcinst with driver]
6. After that you can just use your sqlite odbc connection string. In my case it was something like this: `DRIVER=SQLITE3;Database=Orders.db; LongNames=0; Timeout=1000; NoTXN=0; SyncPragma=NORMAL; StepAPI=0;`

> Sometimes I have found errors when leaving spaces between `Database=` the database name and the last `;` just make sure you dont because if not the driver wont find the .db file

Comment: You may skip the first step since sqlite is a dependency of sqliteodbc.